# updating a multi-embedded data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-mongodb

I want to **insert into an array-list in an embedded data**. I tried several ways but couldn't make it out. My data structure is something like this. The code given here is just a dummy reference to my original data structure

```
 Class X{
    Integer _id;
    Arraylist<Y> objY;
    }

Class Y{
    Integer _id;
    Arraylist<Z> objZ;
    }

Class Z{
        Integer _id;
        String value;
        String oldValue
        }
```

I want to insert a new data into objZ 
I know the id value of Class X an Y.
I am using **Spring mongotemplate**.
Does **Spring Mongo Template** Supports this?
Can someone help me out through this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it hope it might help someone out here, Use aggregetion to do this.

```
Query searchUserQuery = new Query((Criteria.where("_id").is("542264c8e4b098972a1cf60c").and("leads._id").is("2")));// _id is the id of class X
AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(searchUserQuery );  
AggregationOperation group = Aggregation.group("objY");
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.unwind("objY"),match, group);

List<objY> asd=mongoOperation.aggregate(aggregation, "Name_of_ur_collection", B.class).getMappedResults();
ArrayList<Z> s=asd.get(0).getObjZ();
s.add("New Data to be added");
mongoOperation.updateFirst(searchUserQuery, Update.update("objY.$.objZ", s), X.class);
```

This will insert your array list in class Y.

Thanks